# Not able to create a build definition for a specific branch

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-pipelines

I am using Visual Studio Team Services 2015 and I have multiple branches of the source code. I did not have any trouble in branching out the source code, however, I would like to implement Continuous Integration so as to automate the build process. However, I am not able to create a build definition for specific branch. Below are the links to the screenshots. You can see that I have Main branch (trunk/working copy) and version 1.0 branch (released version). However, the branch selection is not available while creating build definition.

[Branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmU6S.png)

[Build Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Fnc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is expected. There is not an option to select a branch for a TFVC team project. You can map the branch you want to build under Repository tab:

[image]

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. It saved me a day!!